# trying to SFTP into host from guest in virtualbox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I went to Devices -> Network Adapters.. -> Port Forwarding and added the following:

Name: SSH
Protocol: TCP
Host IP: 127.0.0.1 (I also tried blank)
Host Port: 22
Guest IP: 127.0.0.1 (I tried blank here as well)
Guest Port: 4022

I then tried the following via my Ubuntu virtual machine:

```
sftp -oPort=4022 username@127.0.0.1
```

And I got the following:

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 4022: Connection refused
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I can connect to the host from the host via port 22 just fine. I allowed port 22 in the firewall but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Name: SSH Protocol: TCP Host IP: 127.0.0.1 (I also tried blank) Host Port: 22
>   Guest IP: 127.0.0.1 (I tried blank here as well) Guest Port: 4022

This sets up a port forward from the *host* to the *guest*, not the other way around. It would accept connections to port 22 on the *host*, and forward those connections to port 4022 on the *guest*.

If you want to connect from the guest to the host, just connect to the host's regular LAN IP address, whatever that is.